# Registering file handlers in code running prior to main()

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm looking into ways to prevent unnecessary clutter in setup code in `main()` as well as various other places. I often have tons of setup code that registers itself with some factory. A standard example is e.g. handlers for various file types.

To avoid having to write this code and instead just make handlers magically work if linked into the application, I figured I could replace the code by something like the following:

test.cc:

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

loader.h:

```
#ifndef LOADER_H_
#define LOADER_H_

#include <functional>

namespace loader {

class Loader {
 public:
  Loader(std::function<void()> f);
};

}  // namespace loader

#define REGISTER_HANDLER(name, f) \
namespace { \
::loader::Loader _macro_internal_ ## name(f); \
}

#endif  // LOADER_H_
```

loader.cc:

```
#include "loader.h"

#include <iostream>

namespace loader {

Loader::Loader(std::function<void()> f) { f(); }

}  // namespace loader
```

a.cc:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "loader.h"

REGISTER_HANDLER(a, []() {
  std::cout << "hello from a" << std::endl;
})
```

The idea here is that `a.cc` would in a real application e.g. call some method where it registers it self as a handler for a certain file type. Compiling the code with `c++ -std=c++11 test.cc loader.cc a.cc` creates a binary that prints "hello from a" while `c++ -std=c++11 test.cc loader.cc` stays silent.

I'm wondering if there's something subtle that I might need to be careful with? For example, if someone creates complex objects in the lambda that is run here, I assume weird things can happen during cleanup for example in a multithreaded application?

Comment: Dont. order of static variable initialization is only guranteed within a single translation unit (i.e a .cpp file). Speaking out of experience, such patterns can cause alot of problems in the long run. Besides that, global state is always a code smell. In the least it makes your code less testable. Instead try a top-down approach.

Comment: One of my concerns was actually that if I register callbacks in a global std::vector, then that vector will be in a different translation unit, so it might not have been constructed when something from another translation unit tries to push into it.

Comment: This part (the global vector being initialized early enough) can be solved by techniques like [nifty counters](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter). This is what the standard library uses to ensure that `std::cout` et al are available during initialization of global variables.

Comment: @del why use global variables at all? Write a class responsible for setup and shutdown and use a pattern like dependency injection. If you really want to have global state you can use singletons to gain control over initialization

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> ... unnecessary clutter in setup code in `main()`  ...
>
> ```
> int main() {
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

This is not preventing unnecessary clutter. This is hiding your initializations. They still occur, but now you have to chase after them. That's really not the way to do it. Also, it will force the use of a lot of global state - in many independent global variables, most probably - which is also a bad thing. Instead, consider writing something like:

```
class my_app_state { /* ... */ };

my_app_state initialize(/* perhaps with argc and argv here? */) {
    // 
    // Your "unnecessary" clutter goes here...
    //
    return whatever;
}

int main() {
    auto app_state = initialize();
    //
    // do stuff involving the app_state...
    //
}
```

and don't try to "game" the program loader.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not guaranteed to work:

> **[basic.start.dynamic]/4** It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

Thus, the initialization of `_macro_internal_a` may be deferred until something in `a.cc` is used. And since nothing in `a.cc` is in fact used, the initialization may not be performed at all.

In practice, linkers tend to discard object files that do not appear to be referenced by anything in the program (especially when those files come from libraries).